# Questions about dataframe partition consistency/safety in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was playing around with Spark and I wanted to try and find a dataframe-only way to assign consecutive ascending keys to dataframe rows that minimized data movement. I found a two-pass solution that gets count information from each partition, and uses that to generate the keys in each partition. It seems to work well in testing (faster than using unpartitioned row_number() or RDDs and zipWithIndex), but I'm not sure if it's safe in general or if it's possible to guarantee safety.

My toy solution is this:

```
def getKeyF(offsetKeyByPartitionDict,initial=1):
   @pandas_udf('long')
   def _internal_udf(s: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
      curKey=initial
      for x in s:
         offsetKey = offsetKeyByPartitionDict[x[0]] #should be the same each time
         yield x.index+curKey+offsetKey
         curKey = curKey + x.size
   return _internal_udf

#Get partition information
rowsWithPartition = rows.select('*',F.spark_partition_id().alias('partition'))
partitionSizes = rowsWithPartition.groupBy('partition').count()
almostAll = Window.orderBy(F.col('partition')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow-1)
#Pass 1: Get rolling sum to get which key each partition should start at. Technically, this does shuffle but it's relatively very small
startingKeyByPartition = dict(partitionSizes.select('partition',(F.coalesce(F.sum('count').over(almostAll),F.lit(0)).alias('startIndex'))).collect())
#Pass 2: Get the keys for each partition
keys = rowsWithPartition.select('businessKey', (getKeyF(startingKeyByPartition,1)('partition')).alias('key'))
```

When I tried this locally on a single-node machine it worked, but that doesn't mean it will work in all situations.

My worries are:

1. I know Iterator[Series]->Iterator[Series] pandas UDFs iterate on Arrow batches, but it never says that the union of all the batches for a single function call is the data for exactly one partition. If there some corner case where this isn't true, this code would break because it assumes it's running on the totality of rows for a given partition id. Is this something I can depend on?
2. Can I really be sure that the 'partition' column is the same for each row in each pass? I know the function is nondeterministic, but does lazy evaluation mean the column is therefore nondeterministic as well? Would caching the rowsWithPartition dataframe ensure the partition column stays the same, or are there weird cases where that wouldn't work, either?
3. If I can't make both those guarantees, is there a way to make this idea safe, or is it DOA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to (1) at least from [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27466#pullrequestreview-353665050). Basically, what I wrote wasn't safe. It works for this version, but it may break in the future.

Still not sure about (2). It seems like if partition ids were allowed to switch arbitrarily, even in situations like if a cluster goes down or a task fails, then it could lead to incorrect results if, say, the dataframe was only partially cached, but I don't know how robust that is.